# Movements In Unity Game

Tags: c#, android, input, unity-game-engine, touch

I have the below c# script which works in parallel with the animator system within Unity. The user presses the right and left arrow keys to move left and right. I want to put this onto device. To do that I tried to use the new unity4.6+ UI system using buttons at bottom of screen but couldn't get it to work. The best option i Think is to use tilt or swipe, preferably tilt. Can anyone look at that script and point me in the right direction as to were the tilt function code would be placed ? Help is much appreciated..

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

// Require these components when using this script
[RequireComponent(typeof (Animator))]
[RequireComponent(typeof (CapsuleCollider))]
[RequireComponent(typeof (Rigidbody))]
public class PlayerControl_S : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.NonSerialized]                  
    public float meshMoveSpeed = 4.0f;

[System.NonSerialized]
public float animSpeed = 1.5f;              // a public setting for overall animator animation speed

private Animator anim;                          // a reference to the animator on the character
private AnimatorStateInfo currentBaseState;         // a reference to the current state of the animator, used for base layer
private AnimatorStateInfo layer2CurrentState;   // a reference to the current state of the animator, used for layer 2

static int reloadState = Animator.StringToHash("Layer2.Reload");                // and are used to check state for various actions to occur

static int switchWeaponState = Animator.StringToHash("Layer2.WeaponSwap");


void Start ()
{
    // initialising reference variables
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();                                        
    if(anim.layerCount ==2)
        anim.SetLayerWeight(1, 1);
}


/*void OnAnimatorMove() //Tells Unity that root motion is handled by the script
{
    if(anim)
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = transform.position;
        newPosition.z += anim.GetFloat("Speed")* meshMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        newPosition.x += anim.GetFloat("Direction") * meshMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = newPosition;
    }
} */

void OnAnimatorMove() //Tells Unity that root motion is handled by the script
{
    if(anim)
    {
        Vector3 newPosition = transform.position;
        newPosition.z += anim.GetFloat("Speed")* meshMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        newPosition.x += anim.GetFloat("Direction") * meshMoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position = newPosition;
    }
} 

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    float h = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");              // setup h variable as our horizontal input axis
    float v = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");                // setup v variables as our vertical input axis
    anim.SetFloat("Speed", 1f);                         // set our animator's float parameter 'Speed' equal to the vertical input axis              
    anim.SetFloat("Direction", h);                      // set our animator's float parameter 'Direction' equal to the horizontal input axis        
    anim.speed = animSpeed;                             // set the speed of our animator to the public variable 'animSpeed'
    //anim.SetLookAtWeight(lookWeight);                 // set the Look At Weight - amount to use look at IK vs using the head's animation
    currentBaseState = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0); // set our currentState variable to the current state of the Base Layer (0) of animation

    //Controls the movement speed
    if(v <= 0.0f)
    {
        meshMoveSpeed = 4;  
    }
    else
    {
        meshMoveSpeed = 6;
    }

    if(anim.layerCount ==2)
    {
        layer2CurrentState = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(1);   // set our layer2CurrentState variable to the current state of the second Layer (1) of animation
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to put tilt controls in Update. You should mostly be using Fixed Update for the build in physics system IE manipulating rigid bodies.

Right now your code is only looking for vertical axis changes for movement speed. You can look into setting what is handled by GetAxis in joystick settings.

Comment: This following code was added to the FixedUpdate function: **`Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero;

  if (Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.Portrait) 
  {
   dir.x = -Input.acceleration.y; 

   if(dir.sqrMagnitude > 1)
   {
    dir.Normalize();
   }

   dir *= Time.deltaTime;
   transform.Translate(dir * meshMoveSpeed);
  }`**
What this does is ...the user tilts device towards them, chartacer moves right but cant move left...i need tilt left to move left and tilt right to move right as supposedd to tilting device towards player...any ideas?